# Show popup after pivot sliding animation

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to show a popup after the pivot sliding animation is finished.

Right now, the popup alert is shown first and behind it the sliding animation goes on.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            SelectHome();
            break;
        case 1:
            SelectTest(); 
            break;
        case 2:
            SelectStatus();
            Alert alert = new Alert();
            alert.Show();
            break;
        case 3:
            SelectAbout();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this WP8 or WP8.1? Silverlight or WinRT?

Comment: It's hardly both WP8 and WinRT.

Comment: what would be the solution for WP8?

Answer (score 1):

Under WP8.1 RunTime you can do it for example like this:

Create an extension of *Pivot* control that would expose its *ScrollViewer*:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
  public class PivotEx : Pivot
  {
    public ScrollViewer exposedSV = null;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        exposedSV = this.GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
    }
  }
```

Once you have it, define in XAML you Pivot:

```
<local:PivotEx x:Name="myPivot" xmlns:local="using:YOurNamespace">
// rest of code
```

Then it's possible to access *ScrollViewer* and subscribe to its *ViewChanged* event:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (sender, e) => myPivot.exposedSV.ViewChanged += pivotsScroll_ViewChanged;
    }

    private async void pivotsScroll_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsIntermediate) await new MessageDialog("After scroll changed!").ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: thnaks i'll try it out...i used a timer to initiate the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is the efficient way to do this but i used a timer to initiate the popup after the scrolling animation of pivot.

```
async Task showAlertWithDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    AlertMessage alert = new AlertMessage();
    alert.show();
}

private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            SelectHome();
            break;
        case 1:
            SelectTest(); 
            break;
        case 2:
            SelectStatus();
            showAlertWithDelay();
            break;
        case 3:
            SelectAbout();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```